# Summation with exponential part

Tags: summation, summation-method

Can anyone help me with calculating below summation?

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{n^2 e^{-a(n^2+b)}}{n^2+b}$,

in which $b$ and $a$ are positive.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Perhaps include this in your question.

Comment: I have no idea about that because I don't know what to do with the exponential part! @Benjamin